# Swift 3 comparing array indexes

Tags: arrays, swift, indexing

If i have two arrays & i want to compare their indexes, for ex:

```
let var a1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
let var a2 = ["3", "2", "3"]
```

And i wanted to print something to say which index wasn't the same, such as:

```
if a1[0] != a2[0] && a1[1] == a2[1] && a1[2] == a2[2]{
print("Index 0 is not the same.")
```

Would i have to write 7 more of those statements to show all 8 possibilities of all correct/all wrong/index 1&1 wrong, etc?

Thank you!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get all indexes like this:

```
let diffIndex = zip(a1, a2).enumerated().filter {$1.0 != $1.1}.map {$0.offset}
```

Explanation:

- `zip` produces a sequence of pairs
- `enumerated()` adds an index to the sequence
- `filter` keeps only pairs with different values
- `map` harvests the index, and builds the sequence of results.

Running this on

```
let a1 = ["1", "2", "3", "4"]
let a2 = ["3", "2", "3", "5"]
```

This produces a sequence `[0, 3]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
let a1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
let a2 = ["3", "2", "3"]

let result = zip(a1, a2).map({ $0 == $1 }).reduce(true, {$0 && $1})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for` loop:

```
for i in 0..<a1.length {
    if a1[i] != a2[i] {
        print("Index \(i) is not the same")
    }
}
```

Generally if you find yourself repeating the same code but with different numbers, you can substitute it with a `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you! Would the same for - loop work if the values were strings instead of integers?

Comment: @3Beard This loop does not make any assumptions about the types of `a1` and `a2` elements, as long as `!=` operator can be applied.

Answer (score 0):

Surely you could do something like this:

```
let a1 = ["1", "2", "3"]
let a2 = ["3", "2", "3"]

var compareResult : [String] = [String]()

if a1.count == a2.count { // Need to check they have same length

    for count in 0..<a1.count {
        let result : String = a1[count] == a2[count] ? "MATCH" : "MISMATCH"
        compareResult.append(result)
    }

    print(compareResult)
    // Do something more interesting with compare result...
}
```