# Filter compare array same index swift 4

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, compare

My case is create multiple choice questions, and i want to compare array in the same index

Correct answer:

```
[3, 2, 0, 2, 2]
```

User answer:

```
[3, 2, 3, 1, 1]
```

The expected output:

```
[3,2]
```

And this is the code

```
let filteredArray = correctAnswer.filter{ userAnswer.contains($0) }
print(filteredArray)
```

But the output:

```
[3, 2, 2, 2]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more useful to determine the *indices* of the correct answers?

Comment: Yea i was gonna ask what would be expected output for [3,2,0,2,2] and [3,2,3,1,2]

Comment: Strongly related: [Swift 3 comparing array indexes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39987260/1187415)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to compare two array index by index then you can use `compactMap` with `zip`.

```
let correctAns = [3, 2, 0, 2, 2]
let userAns = [3, 2, 3, 1, 1]
let finalAns = zip(correctAns, userAns).compactMap({ $0 == $1 ? $0 : nil })
print(finalAns) // [3, 2]
```

**Edit:** You can even simplified this by using **`@MartinR`** suggestion.

```
let finalAns = zip(correctAns, userAns).filter(==).map { $1 }
```

If you want index of correct answer than you can get like this.

```
let finalAnsIndex = zip(correctAns, userAns).enumerated().compactMap({ $0.element.0 == $0.element.1 ? $0.offset : nil })
print(finalAnsIndex) // [0, 1]
```

Comment: Beat me by seconds `let matches = zip(correct,user).filter({$0 == $1 }).map{$1}`

Comment: Or `.filter(==).map { $1 }`

Comment: @MartinR Great suggestion

Comment: better to use the tuple names whenever possible to improve readability `compactMap{$0.element.0 == $0.element.1 ? $0.offset : nil}`

Comment: @LeoDabus Thanks for the suggestion, Edited answer with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can `zip` the two arrays to filter the answers that was correct:

```
zip(userGuesses, correctAnswers).filter { (guess, answer) in guess == answer }
```

Further, if you want only the right answers you can map the zipped sequence to get only the users answers:

```
zip(userGuesses, correctAnswers)
    .filter { (guess, answer) in guess == answer }
    .map { (guess, _) in guess }
```

---

That said, this doesn't say which questions was answered correctly. For example: If the correct answers were `[1,2,3,2,1,3]` and the user answered `[1,3,1,2,3,3]` it wouldn't be possible to know which questions the user got right (since both `#1, #3`, `#1, #6`, and `#5, #6`, all result in `[1,3]`

Comment: Yes, but the two values are the same so it's easy to ignore either.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have just specified the return type of your solution.